# Unique summations of $k$ rows of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a matrix $M$ with $R$ rows and $C$ columns, $R>C$.

Rows are considered distinct/unique if there exists at least one column in which they differ. In $M$, the composition of each row is different from all others, meaning each row differs from all others in at least one column, although some entries may be identical between $2$ rows. Therefore all rows in $M$ are distinct.

A summation of rows is done by summing each column seperately. So the summation of $R_1=(2,7,3) , R_2=(11,2,1) , R_3=(5,7,5)$ is $R_4=(2+11+5,7+2+7,3+1+5)=(18,16,9)$

Is there any way to count how many unique row summations of $k$ rows of $M$ exist? Again, a unique summation would be one that differs from all others in at least one column. Important to say that it's possible that $k>R$, meaning a row may be chosen multiple times in the summation.

Comment: How many unique summations are there if $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @AirMike It depends on what is your value of $k$. It varies accordingly.

Comment: Let’s say $k = 2$.

Comment: Then there are $5$ unique row summations: $(2,4),(3,5),(4,6),(5,7),(6,8)$. Notice that picking 2 times the 2nd row is equivalent to picking the 1st and 3rd (both result in $(4,6)$)